# base64 to binary output to browser

Tags: asp-classic

I have an image in database as a dataurl:

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAA...
```

I want to output the image as a file to the browser

```
r=split(rs("image"),";")
s=split(r(1),",")
imgdata=base64decode(s(1))
Response.Contenttype="image/png"
response.binarywrite(imgdata)
```

The resulting file is twice the size of len(imgdata); i first thought it only padded 8 bit to 16, as this dump shows.

```
0000000 2030 0050 004e 0047 000d 000a 001a 000a
0000010 0000 0000 0000 000d 0049 0048 0044 0052
0000020 0000 0000 0001 0063 0000 0000 0001 00fe
0000030 0008 0006 0000 0000 0000 0049 003a 006f
0000040 007c 0000 0000 0020 0000 0049 0044 0041
```

But another place in the resulting file:

```
0000210 2014 004b 2022 00eb 203a 007e 0178 00ee
0000220 00da 00dd 00a5 007b 0178 00af 017e 00a3
0000230 003a 0066 00f6 00bd 007a 00e5 0053 00cf
```

there are words with the high order byte set.

Is it a codepage problem?

If I read a file from disk and binarywrites it, the image is fine.

Comment: If your classic asp app is running in IIS7 or IIS8... It would be easier to create a c# dll and expose it to com, then just use Convert.FromBase64.  I did this for the entire Text Namespace, I even have a StringBuilder com exposed I can call in classic asp.  E.g.  Server.CreateObject("XYZ.Text.StringBuilder").  It works because classic asp can be run in integrated mode side by side with the .Net CLR which is already on those servers anyways since 2008 r2 ships with 3.5 and sp 1 was 4.5.2, and windows 2012 ships with 4.5.

Comment: Thanks, but the 4 lines in my answer below is easy and working for me.

Comment: Yeah, just might not be the most efficient or best performing way to do it, if it causes issues later or is really slow, revisit the com+ dll idea, it's easy to, and really fast.

Comment: No problem, the image is cached anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I replaced the base64decode with this:

```
Set objXML = Server.CreateObject("MSXml2.DOMDocument")
Set objDocElem = objXML.createElement("Base64Data")
objDocElem.DataType = "bin.base64"
objDocElem.text = s(1) 'the base64-encoded string
imgdata=objDocElem.NodeTypedValue
```

Now the resulting image is correct, and the decoding is 100 times faster (it feals)